# Looking for shapefiles for Canadian shale plays with labels and/or meta data about the plays

Tags: shapefile, canada, oil-gas

I work for a company in the oil and gas industry.  We are making a geospatial map with mapbox and leaflet.  Our task is to show shale plays in relation to other industry items like well sites.  We have completed the work in the U.S. and gathered most of our data from RigData and EIA.gov; these are both US based and do not contain other countries in the dataset. I have searched the BC Ministry of Natural Gas; BC Ministry of Energy and Mines; Alberta Geological Survey; http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/ and googled several combinations of "Canada/ian" and "Shale play/s".  So far, I cannot find a shapefile that says [shale play name] shapefile. The shape files should be able to look like this [map](http://pacwestcp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/PacWest_Canada-Key-Plays_Feb-2013.jpg).  Can someone help point me to a dataset that can reproduce the shale plays and names?

Comment: http://www.seitel.com/CA/Pages/default.aspx?c=CA has Plays them but there is a power outage in downtown Calgary they do provide shapefiles

Comment: This site is great; it looks exactly like what we've made in house; heatmap and all too. will look to see if I can download their shapefiles

Comment: unless im just being too slow to see it; I can't find any shapefiles; the dom just lists the plays as jpgs using the google api to host them... can you suggest where the shapefiles get downloaded from? for example [here](http://mt0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US&lyrs=kml%3Acu7AogJSscpHoBmzczpu5U…%3Bts%3A47116226%7Ckv%3A3&x=3&y=5&z=4&w=256&h=256&source=apiv3&token=66135)

Comment: the shapefiles they list are just for seismic activity; I can't find any shapefiles for just the shale plays points or that include them;

Comment: http://204.12.153.232/GEarth/World/PNAV13.kmz is the plays just convert to shapefile in qgis (or other gis)

Comment: I found some for alberta here [ags.gov.ca](http://ags.gov.ab.ca/publications/pubs.aspx?tkey=shale%20gas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File from the Website is in KMZ format

204.12.153.232/GEarth/World/PNAV13.kmz

Loaded into QGIS and saved as a shapefile.

Labels are in the Name Field which is then labelled.
[image]

Comment: I'll mark yours as the answer, since I don't have access to qgis.  I know this is a gis forum, it's also the only place that I found help at.  I'm converting from shape to geojson for our applications purposes. If anyone is curious there is a online converter for shapefile to geojson [here](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/)